# How do I bound a trait with a supertrait that uses the trait's associated type as a parameter?

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Trait` with an associated type `Trait::Associated`. I am trying to bound the trait by requiring that it be indexable by its associated type, as shown here:

```
use std::ops::Index;

pub trait Trait: Index<Trait::Associated> {
    type Associated;
}
```

However, the compiler complains that the associated type is ambiguous

> ```
> error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
>  --> src/main.rs:3:24
>   |
> 3 | pub trait Trait: Index<Trait::Associated> {
>   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type
>   |
>   = note: specify the type using the syntax `<Type as Trait>::Associated`
> ```

I also tried referring to the associated type as `Self::Associated`, but  then the compiler protests about a cyclic reference between the type and the trait:

> ```
> error[E0391]: cyclic dependency detected
>  --> src/main.rs:3:1
>   |
> 3 | pub trait Trait: Index<Self::Associated> {
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cyclic reference
>   |
> note: the cycle begins when computing the supertraits of `Trait`...
>  --> src/main.rs:3:1
>   |
> 3 | pub trait Trait: Index<Self::Associated> {
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   = note: ...which then again requires computing the supertraits of `Trait`, completing the cycle.
> ```

Finally, I also tried explicitly implementing `Index` for `Trait`:

```
pub trait Trait {
    type Associated;
}

impl<T: Trait> Index<T::Associated> for T {
    type Output = str;

    fn index(&self, associated: T::Associated) -> &'static str {
        "sup"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that fails too:

> ```
> error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`)
>  --> src/main.rs:7:1
>   |
> 7 | impl<T: Trait> Index<T::Associated> for T {
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
>   |
>   = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
> ```

Am I trying to do something unreasonable here? Is there a way of achieving something similar, without having to use generics?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd462df10e06bb6a86b29461fed3975e&version=stable&mode=debug).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are close, very close.

The `Trait` does not assume that any reference to `Trait` in its definition refers to the current type. After all, you could wish to refer to other types also implementing `Trait`.

In order to specify that you want a specific type, you should heed the compilers note: use `<Type as Trait>::Associated`, where `Type` is the current type.

When defining the `Trait`, how do you refer to the concrete type for which it will be instantiated? You use `Self`!

The solution is:

```
pub trait Trait: Index<<Self as Trait>::Associated> {
    type Associated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Incidentally, is there a way to make my third attempt work (the one where trait definition and `impl` block are separate)? If I try to use `Self` in the `impl` line, rustc complains.

Comment: @Jean: the syntax would be `impl<T: Trait> Index<<T as Trait>::Associated> for T` but there is a coherence issue here. You cannot only implement a `trait` from another crate for a type of your own crate (to avoid multiple people providing conflicting implementations of a given trait for a given type). Here, `T` is not restricting to the types of your crate... so it is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following provides the semantics you want, taking the approach of your second attempt.

```
pub trait Trait {
    type Associated;
}

impl<T> Index<T> for Trait<Associated = T> {
    type Output = str;

    fn index(&self, associated: T) -> &'static str {
        "sup"
    }
}
```