# How to create a trait that specifies the associated type of a supertrait?

Tags: rust

I want to create an abstract trait that specifies an indexing type and a value type where any struct that implements the trait has to implement `Index<IndexType>` and `IndexMut<IndexType>` and defines the `Output` type which stays the same in every struct that implements the trait.

I tried creating a trait, but it seems I can't specify the output type:

```rust
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

struct Coord;
struct LightValue;

trait LightMap: Index<Coord> + IndexMut<Coord> {}

impl LightMap {
    type Output = LightValue;
}
```

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
 --> src/lib.rs:8:6
  |
8 | impl LightMap {
  |      ^^^^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn LightMap`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(bare_trait_objects)]` on by default

error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Output` (from the trait `std::ops::Index`) must be specified
 --> src/lib.rs:8:6
  |
8 | impl LightMap {
  |      ^^^^^^^^ associated type `Output` must be specified

error[E0202]: associated types are not yet supported in inherent impls (see #8995)
 --> src/lib.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     type Output = LightValue;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I don't specify the output type then `associated type Output must be specified` happens wherever I try to use the trait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place the restriction of the associated type on the supertrait:

```
trait LightMap: Index<Coord, Output = LightValue> + IndexMut<Coord> {}
```

See also:

- [Traits with stricter associated type bounds than supertrait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47018493/155423)
- [How do I bound a trait with a supertrait that uses the trait's associated type as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35799682/155423)
- [Constraints on associated trait types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33520049/155423)
- [Matching a generic parameter to an associated type in an impl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29345708/155423)
- [Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070559/155423)
- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)
- [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)